# Get Lat Long from Google

Tags: ruby, json, geocoding

I want code where I put the location to search and it will return the lat and long. I am using Google's Geocode API. I have code that sends the request etc., and it returns the following:

```
{"results"=>[{"address_components"=>[{"long_name"=>"London", "short_name"=>"London", "types"=>["locality", "political"]}, {"long_name"=>"United Kingdom", "short_name"=>"GB", "types"=>["country", "political"]}], "formatted_address"=>"London, UK", "geometry"=>{"bounds"=>{"northeast"=>{"lat"=>51.6723432, "lng"=>0.1478797}, "southwest"=>{"lat"=>51.38494009999999, "lng"=>-0.3514683}}, "location"=>{"lat"=>51.51121389999999, "lng"=>-0.1198244}, "location_type"=>"APPROXIMATE", "viewport"=>{"northeast"=>{"lat"=>51.6723432, "lng"=>0.1478797}, "southwest"=>{"lat"=>51.38494009999999, "lng"=>-0.3514683}}}, "types"=>["locality", "political"]}], "status"=>"OK"}
```

I want to get the Lat and Lng from a reply like above, and assign them to two variables. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are several `"lat"` and `"lng"` in the hash. Which one do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
h = {"results"=>[{"address_components"=>[{"long_name"=>"London", "short_name"=>"London", "types"=>["locality", "political"]}, {"long_name"=>"United Kingdom", "short_name"=>"GB", "types"=>["country", "political"]}], "formatted_address"=>"London, UK", "geometry"=>{"bounds"=>{"northeast"=>{"lat"=>51.6723432, "lng"=>0.1478797}, "southwest"=>{"lat"=>51.38494009999999, "lng"=>-0.3514683}}, "location"=>{"lat"=>51.51121389999999, "lng"=>-0.1198244}, "location_type"=>"APPROXIMATE", "viewport"=>{"northeast"=>{"lat"=>51.6723432, "lng"=>0.1478797}, "southwest"=>{"lat"=>51.38494009999999, "lng"=>-0.3514683}}}, "types"=>["locality", "political"]}], "status"=>"OK"}

lat, lng = h["results"].first["geometry"]["location"].values_at("lat", "lng")
lat # => 51.51121389999999
lng # => -0.1198244
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to specify, but they are the lat long I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

```
lat, lng = *result['results'][0]['geometry']['location'].values
```